# Django round in subquery

Tags: django, orm, subquery

hi i am getting the progress percentage of each project in a ListView with subquery with the following code

```
class projects(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project_list.html'
    ordering = ['project_title']
    paginate_by = 10
    queryset = Project.objects.annotate(
        todo_done=Count('todo', filter=Q(todo__state=True)) * 100 / Count('todo'),
        todo_left=Count('todo', filter=Q(todo__state=False)) * 100 / Count('todo'),
    )
```

in a project I have 12 tasks, 8 finished and 4 in progress. The system returns 66% completed and 33% in progress, whose sum is 99% and not 100%

```
{{ project.todo_done }}
{{ project.todo_left }}
```

[image]

part of the bar is blank because the 1% is missing. I try to use round as follows but it is not possible

```
todo_done=round(Count('todo', filter=Q(todo__state=True)) * 100 / Count('todo')),
```

```
TypeError: type CombinedExpression doesn't define __round__ method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use Python's `round`, since that does not understand anything about database expressions. However you can make use of a [**`Round`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#round):

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import Round

queryset = Project.objects.annotate(
    todo_done=Round(Count('todo', filter=Q(todo__state=True)) * 100 / Count('todo')),
    todo_left=100*Count('todo') - F('todo_done'),
)
```

If the `state` of the `Todo`s can only be `True` or `False`, it is probably better to subtract `todo_done` from 100 times `Count('todo')`, since then it is normally guaranteed that the two will sum up to 100, unless of course there are *no* related `Todo`s.

Some databases will use integer division if the two operands are integers, you can prevent this by casting it to a `FloatField`:

```
from django.db.models import F, FloatField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, Round

queryset = Project.objects.annotate(
    todo_done=Round(
        Cast(Count('todo', filter=Q(todo__state=True)), output_field=FloatField())
        * 100 / Count('todo')
    ),
    todo_left=100*Count('todo') - F('todo_done'),
)
```

Comment: the queries are related to the todo table, but even guaranteeing 100 in the final sum with the subtraction in todo_left, I keep seeing that it doesn't round correctly. |||
 
todo_done=Round(Count('todo', filter=Q(todo__state=True)) * 100 / Count('todo')), todo_left=100 - Round(Count('todo', filter=Q(todo__state=True)) * 100 / Count('todo')),

Comment: I tried this locally and for MySQL it works, for PostgreSQL you probably will need to cast to a `FloatField`, since otherwise it makes integer division.

Comment: @Drennos: see an edit for databases that use integer division.

Comment: you mean change the BooleanField to FloatField?

Comment: @Drennos: no, cast the `Count(...)` of the `Todo`s to a float.

Comment: dear @Willem Van Onsem, the solution without using FloatField or Cast was to add a decimal to the multiplication by 100. `todo_done=Round(Count('todo', filter=Q(todo__state=True)) * 100.0 / Count('todo')),todo_left=Round(Count('todo', filter=Q(todo__state=False)) * 100.0 / Count('todo')),`. Thanks a lot